# Clicking on all like buttons with same class name but different id's that all have one common word using Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

So I'm trying to make a script that likes everything on a page, all the posts on the page have the like buttons with the same class but different id's, one id is like-container-79283848 and the second like is like-container-79294939, how do I click all the like buttons in the same time and future like buttons that are going to be posted?

```
like_container = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('reaction-container qa-class-reaction-container qa-test-like-reaction tooltip-like-reaction') # I think this will access all the like buttons
for x in range (0,???????)): #here I'm trying to make a list of all the like buttons, but I don't know what range to make, there are way too many numbers after the like-container id!
    if like_container[x].is_displayed():
        like_container[x].click()
```

the number after the like-container- has 9 figures

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand I think you want your range to be '(len(like_container))' because the like_container indexes are from 0-len(like_container) - 1. So by just putting 'for x in range(len(like_container)):'. For the part where you have to like them "all at the same time", are you looking to like them at the EXACT same time (like to the millisecond) or you are fine with have some delay between likes?